# OpenCV setup with Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am trying to set up OpenCV for a project in Xcode but have a compilation error I can not seem to fix.

here is an example error:

```
'opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp' file not found
```

Similar errors occur for other include files.

I could be wrong but I think it should be looking in `usr/local/lib` for all the include files.

and I have the following in that directory:

```
justin-macbook-pro:lib Justin$ pwd
/usr/local/lib
justin-macbook-pro:lib Justin$ ls
libopencv_calib3d.3.0.0.dylib       libopencv_objdetect.3.0.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.3.0.dylib     libopencv_objdetect.a
libopencv_calib3d.a         libopencv_objdetect.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.dylib         libopencv_photo.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib      libopencv_photo.3.0.dylib
libopencv_core.3.0.dylib        libopencv_photo.a
libopencv_core.a            libopencv_photo.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib            libopencv_shape.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_features2d.3.0.0.dylib    libopencv_shape.3.0.dylib
libopencv_features2d.3.0.dylib      libopencv_shape.a
libopencv_features2d.a          libopencv_shape.dylib
libopencv_features2d.dylib      libopencv_stitching.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_flann.3.0.0.dylib     libopencv_stitching.3.0.dylib
libopencv_flann.3.0.dylib       libopencv_stitching.a
libopencv_flann.a           libopencv_stitching.dylib
libopencv_flann.dylib           libopencv_superres.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_hal.a             libopencv_superres.3.0.dylib
libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib       libopencv_superres.a
libopencv_highgui.3.0.dylib     libopencv_superres.dylib
libopencv_highgui.a         libopencv_ts.a
libopencv_highgui.dylib         libopencv_video.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib     libopencv_video.3.0.dylib
libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.dylib       libopencv_video.a
libopencv_imgcodecs.a           libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib       libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib       libopencv_videoio.3.0.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib     libopencv_videoio.a
libopencv_imgproc.a         libopencv_videoio.dylib
libopencv_imgproc.dylib         libopencv_videostab.3.0.0.dylib
libopencv_ml.3.0.0.dylib        libopencv_videostab.3.0.dylib
libopencv_ml.3.0.dylib          libopencv_videostab.a
libopencv_ml.a              libopencv_videostab.dylib
libopencv_ml.dylib          pkgconfig
libopencv_objdetect.3.0.0.dylib     python2.7
justin-macbook-pro:lib Justin$
```

The steps I followed to set it up to this point is [here](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation at the link you provide, the header files are at `/usr/local/include` not `/usr/local/lib` which is where the libraries are.

Check that you followed this step

> Double Click the Header Search Paths option, then Click the plus icon
>   Type in the following /usr/local/include

correctly.